# gcloud python SDK serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/services?filter=state:ENABLED' to list services v1beta1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The gcloud [serviceusage.googleapis.com](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest) has versions v1 and v1beta1.

v1 includes method [services.list](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/list) to list all the services in a project.

```
serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/services?filter=state:ENABLED'
```

v1 does not include methods for service quotas.

v1beta includes methods for [Service Quota Limits](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/services.consumerQuotaMetrics.limits.adminOverrides), but in v1beta1 [services.list](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/services/list) method is deprecated - as is services.get and services.batchEnable (*The last has a note that says to use v1 instead*).

Is there an way to list services in v1beta1 that is not deprecated?

I am using the Python SDK which only covers v1 in the documentation, but allows v1beta1 version in the setup

```
SERVICE_USAGE_MANAGER = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1beta1', credentials=credentials,  cache_discovery=False)
```

Can I safely continue to use v1 for services.list even though it is deprecated in v1beta1?

Comment: Have you checked this document on [Deprecated API migration guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a kubernetes link, but it did  help me realise that the v1beta1 functions are deprecated by the (newer?) v1 functions. I had it the other way round.

Comment: Since your issue is resolved can you post the solution you have followed for greater visibility of the community.